# Hide tons of `E/emuglGLESv2_enc` logs from Flutter console

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting tons of errors like this:

```
E/emuglGLESv2_enc(17028): a vertex attribute index out of boundary is detected. Skipping corresponding vertex attribute. buf=0x7694c2bb04e0
E/emuglGLESv2_enc(17028): Out of bounds vertex attribute info: clientArray? 0 attribute 13 vbo 1058 allocedBufferSize 48 bufferDataSpecified? 1 wantedStart 0 wantedEnd 133020
```

Is there a way to hide/ignore those errors OR completely hide the native logs and only show the flutter logs?

Comment: which IDE you are using ?

Comment: @Swayangjit I am using visual code